# Initiated delegated field became null in a closure, Groovy

Tags: groovy, annotations, closures

Groovy Version: 2.4.3 JVM: 1.8.0_60 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Canonical
class A {
    def f() {
        map = [:] //map is not null
        3.times {
            assert map != null // failed, map is null?!
        }
    }

    @Delegate
    Map map
}
new A().f()
```

When I call f(), I got an assertion failed, which means map is null. But if I remove annotation '@Delegate', then there won't be any problem. Or if the assertion is not in a closure, no problem too. My question is why delegated field behave different in or out of a closure? If it's because map in a closure is not the same object in class A, why it works after annotation removed?

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Canonical
class A {
    def f() {
        map = [:]
        3.times {
            assert map != null // No problem, map is not null
        }
    }

    Map map
}
new A().f()
```

Or

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Canonical
class A {
    def f() {
        map = [:]
        assert map != null //no problem too
    }

    @Delegate
    Map map
}
new A().f()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the `@Delegate` annotation, your class essentially becomes an implementation of `java.util.Map` that delegates its calls to it's field `map`. The reference to `map` inside your assertion closure is treated as a `this.getAt('map')` call instead of a reference to the `map` field. Since there's no value mapped to key `map`, the assertion fails.

Maybe this makes it a little clearer:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Canonical
class A {
    def f() {
        map = [map:'not null'] // delegated map has key 'map'
        3.times {
            assert map == 'not null'
        }
    }

    @Delegate
    Map map
}
new A().f()
```

The weirdness primarily has to do with the fact that the assertion is done within a closure, which has [resolve strategy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#OWNER_FIRST) that dictates how references are resolved, which includes use of the metaclass. Remove the closure and the `@Delegate` annotation no longer makes a difference.

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Canonical
class A {
    def f() {
        assert map != null
    }

    @Delegate
    Map map = [:]
}
new A().f()
```